# How to select rows that match all items in a list in Athena (using python)

Tags: python, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-athena

I am using the following code to make some queries to AWS Athena:

```
import os
import boto
import boto3
import pyspark
import botocore
import botocore.session
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

# aws credemtials 
load_dotenv('/home/brenda/Desktop/env_vars/bmartin_aws.env', override = True)
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('ACCESS_KEY') 
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .getOrCreate()

## read matrix from athena
# Set the boto library connection to Athena and S3
client = boto3.client('athena', 
    aws_access_key_id = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
    aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
    region_name = 'us-west-2' )

s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
    aws_access_key_id = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 
    aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, 
    region_name = 'us-west-2')

bucket_name = 'otr-files'
#srcPath = 'path/in/bucket'
srcPath = 'prod/routes_optimization/osrm_cost_matrix/data_athena'

bucket_name = 'otr-files'
#srcPath = 'path/in/bucket'
srcPath = 'prod/routes_optimization/osrm_cost_matrix/data_athena'

######### HERE IS MY QUERY #########
response = client.start_query_execution(
            QueryString = 'SELECT * FROM osrm_cost_matrix',
            QueryExecutionContext = {'Database': 'kof_distance_matrix'},
            ResultConfiguration = {'OutputLocation': 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket_name, srcPath), }
        )

# Get execution data
execution_data = client.get_query_execution(QueryExecutionId = response['QueryExecutionId'])

# Get execution status
status = execution_data['QueryExecution']['Status']['State']

# Get output location
data_output_location = execution_data['QueryExecution']['ResultConfiguration']['OutputLocation']

# Get file name and s3 path to file
srcFileName = '/'.join(data_output_location.split('/')[-1:])
srcFileWithPath = srcPath + srcFileName

# Transfer file to df (Pyspark)
original_matrix = spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").options(header=True).load(data_output_location)
```

And the original_matrix dataframe looks like this:

```
+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+------------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
|client_id_x|client_id_y|   lat_x|   lng_x|   lat_y|   lng_y|   dist|              time|      date|        geoid_x|        geoid_y|
+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+------------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 0700001710| 0700001760|-23.6753|-46.6788|-23.6346|-46.6057|14210.2|            21.045|2021-04-25|8da81000890577f|8da81001b0b353f|
| 0700001710| 0700002137|-23.6753|-46.6788|-23.6309|-46.7059| 7457.9|             12.01|2021-04-25|8da81000890577f|8da810056a5673f|
```

That code works just fine, however I would like to retrieve rows where client_id_x match all elements in a certain list. My list `clients_list` looks like this:

```
clients_list = ['B201', '0700001710', '0700001760', '0700002137', '0700002497', '0700006430', '0700002866', '0700006457', '0700006459', '0700006594', '0700006873',
 '0700014578', '0700008285', '0700009268', '0700011876', '0700014507', '0700014756', '0700014666', '0700016016', '0700014806', '0700014849', '0700014853']
```

And I would like to execute this query:

```
SELECT * FROM osrm_cost_matrix WHERE client_id_x IN (clients_list)
```

However is not working. I am getting the following error:

```
Path does not exist: s3://otr-files/prod/routes_optimization/osrm_cost_matrix/data_athena/6126c412-f5dc-40cf-b079-d442d60f876a.csv;
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: To inject your list into your SQL query you should use this : ",".join([f"'{x}'" for x in clients_list]). But I don't think this is your main problem here

Answer (score 2):

Check your Athena query state, I reckon it may fail. And if it does, you can still get a valid `data_output_location`, but there won't be any file. Hence `spark.read` will fail with "Path does not exist" (fully correctly).

- Maybe you've forgot to replace `clients_list` with its values like:

```py
QueryString=f"SELECT * FROM osrm_cost_matrix WHERE client_id_x IN ({', '.join(clients_list)})"
```

- Wait for the query ends, it could take some time.